# Solving $B = 10 \log\left(\frac{D}{A}\right)$ for $D$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How would I rearrange terms $$B = 10 \log\left( \dfrac{D}{A} \right)$$ to make $D$ the subject of the equation?

Also, if $B = 20$, what would be $D$?

Comment: what kind of $\log$ it is?

Answer (score 0):

from your equation we get
$$\frac{B}{10}=\log\left(\frac{D}{A}\right)$$ if the $log$ has the base $10$ we get
$$10^{B/10}\cdot A=D$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $b > 0$ with $b \neq 1$ denote the base of the logarithm. Then
$$
B = 10 \log_b \left( \dfrac{D}{A} \right)
\,\Longleftrightarrow\,
\dfrac{B}{10} = \log_b \left( \dfrac{D}{A} \right)
\,\Longleftrightarrow\,
b^{B / 10} = \dfrac{D}{A}
\,\Longleftrightarrow\,
A \cdot b^{B / 10} = D \;.
$$
So, if $B = 20$, we obtain:

> $$D = A \cdot b^{2}$$

<sup>(Move the mouse over the yellow box to see the result.)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> $$B = 10 \log\left( \dfrac{D}{A} \right)$$

Assume your $\log$ is in base $b$, where $b=e$ or $b=10$

$$\frac{B}{10}=\log_b \left( \dfrac{D}{A} \right)~~~\Rightarrow ~~~b^{\frac{B}{10}}=b^{\log_b \left( \dfrac{D}{A} \right)}=\frac{D}{A}~~~\Rightarrow~~~ D=A\cdot b^{\frac{B}{10}}$$